# Mixing materials using color ramps (and distributing with a random seed)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, procedural

I'm creating some procedural abstract art in Blender. My goal is to create a material that mixes multiple shaders, with a seed driving the distribution of the mixed shaders across my geometry.

Right now I think I've got it working, but since I'm pretty new to materials in Blender it would be great if someone could take a look at what I've done to make sure I'm getting it right :) I want to make sure that:

- I'm using the color ramps correctly to cleanly divide up my mixed shaders (I don't want any shaders to blend together and affect each other, if that makes sense?)
- My distribution of shaders is random, but even.
- Even if what I'm doing is correct, there's not a more efficient/better way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is my material setup:
[image]

Here is the result on my geometry (I'm using ugly colors for now, just so we can see what we're doing):
[image]

And here is the random seed in action, affecting the distribution of the mixed shaders.
[image]

If what I've done so far shows a misunderstanding of how any of these material nodes should be used, an explanation would be greatly appreciated -- as a heads up, it's entirely possible that I stumbled upon my current solution by accident! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello :). I think you've got it right - this is a good way to randomly combine multiple shaders. And the White noise texture is a nice touch :).

Comment: Do you foresee wanting to vary other attributes of the surface than color? If color only, you could tighten it up a bit.. (nice result, BTW)

Comment: Thanks gang! And yes, I’ll be looking to vary all sorts of attributes eventually, which is why I set it up with multiple Principled Shaders in anticipation :)